# Converting blog url into a data url and sending it to database for storage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

With the following code I have down below. I would like to modify it so that it will convert the blob url variable(url) below into a data url. Javascript Filereader should get the job done, but I would also like to send it to database for storage using ajax call.

```
Recorder.diplayRecord = function(blob, filename) {
    var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
    var displayRecord = document.getElementById("displayRecord");
    //link.href = url;
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var au = document.createElement('audio');
    var hf = document.createElement('a');

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

    au.controls = true;
    au.src = url;
    hf.href = url;
    hf.download = 'audio_recording_' + new Date().getTime() + '.wav';
    hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
    while (displayRecord.lastChild) displayRecord.removeChild(displayRecord.lastChild);
    li.appendChild(au);
    li.appendChild(hf);
    displayRecord.appendChild(li);
```

Comment: Piece at OP missing closing `}` ?

Comment: yes i forgot to add it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Recorder.diplayRecord = function(blob, filename) {
    var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
    var displayRecord = document.getElementById("displayRecord");
    //link.href = url;
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var au = document.createElement('audio');
    var hf = document.createElement('a');

    var reader = new FileReader();       
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      if (e.target.readyState === 2) {
        var _data = e.target.result;
        // `POST` `data-uri`
        $.post("database/url/", {"data": _data})
        .then(
           // `success`
           function(data, textStatus) {
             console.log(textStatus)
         } 
           // `error`
         , function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)   
         })
       };
    };        
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

    au.controls = true;
    au.src = url;
    hf.href = url;
    hf.download = 'audio_recording_' + new Date().getTime() + '.wav';
    hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
    while (displayRecord.lastChild) displayRecord.removeChild(displayRecord.lastChild);
    li.appendChild(au);
    li.appendChild(hf);
    displayRecord.appendChild(li);
    // adding closing `}`
    };
```

See

[FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

[jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: wait... its outputting something like this

Comment: <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: data in

Comment: Not certain what describing ? html returned from which portion of piece ? Thanks

Comment: idk im not sure what happened , it was working at first but now its sending me html tags . also i changed it to this

    var reader = new FileReader();       
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      if (e.target.readyState === 2) {
        var _data = e.target.result;
        // `POST` `data-uri`
        $.post("test.php", {"data": _data}, 
          function(data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
          });
       };
    };        
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

Comment: Expected response from `test.php` ?

Comment: yes this is the php response . its displaying html content

Comment: What is the _expected_ response ? Does `test.php` received `data-uri` string ? If possible , can post `test.php` ?

Comment: alright its working fine now. I think why it wasn't working was because the alert window with the data object in it didn't get closed.

Comment: Nice debugging ;) Answer meet requirement of Question ? Thanks